# React Native Drawer is not totaly closed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation-drawer

I'm working at a ReactNative app and I want to create a drawer with right position.

#### Problem:

The problem is, if I change position to right a small part of it is always on the screen. When I open it, it takes the left position:

#### Drawer closed

[image: pic of the drawer when its closed]

#### Drawer open

[image: pic of the drawer when its open]

#### react native drawer version:

```
"@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.1.8",
```

#### Drawer code:

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();    
const DrawerContent = (props) => {
  const { navigation } = props;
  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView {...props} scrollEnabled={false}>
      <Block flex={0.4} margin={20} bottom center>
        <Image
          source={require("../assets/icon.png")}
          resizeMode="center"
          style={styleDrawer.avatar}
        />
        <Text title padding margin center>
          {"دروس وملخصات باكالوريا "}
        </Text>
      </Block>
      <Block>
        <DrawerItem
          label="الصفحة الرئيسية"
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate("HomeScreen")}
          style={styleDrawer.drawerItem}
          labelStyle={styleDrawer.labelStyle}
          icon={() => (
            <AntDesign
              name="home"
              size={24}
              color="black"
              style={styleDrawer.icon}
            />
          )}
        />
      </Block>
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
  );
};
export default () => {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      drawerType="slide"
      overlayColor="transparent"
      drawerStyle={styleDrawer.drawerStyles}
      initialRouteName="Dashbord"
      screenOptions={{
        drawerPosition: "right",
        headerShown: false,
        activeBackgroundColor: "transparent",
        activeTintColor: "white",
        inactiveTintColor: "white",
      }}
      sceneContainerStyle={{
        justifyContent: "center",
      }}
      drawerContent={(props) => {
        return <DrawerContent {...props} />;
      }}
    >
      <Drawer.Screen name="Screens">
        {(props) => <Screens {...props} />}
      </Drawer.Screen>
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
};
```

#### App.js Code:

```
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import Drawer from "./src/Drawer";
import "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./src/redux/store";
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Drawer />
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: your posted code does not contain the hello. so go for it an let us know the source of this.

Comment: @Gismo1337 i posted it

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `drawerWidth` on `Drawer.Navigator`

```
drawerWidth={Dimensions.get("window").width}
```